# Angular JS +ASP.NET WEB API+SITEMINDER

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, siteminder

We are building a web app on angularJS and WEB API 2.2, basic funtctionality of the app is to download documents from certain Fileshare.
Talking in architectural details, these two apps (angular JS and REST API) will be hosted on two different websites(ie clientAPP.com and RESTAPI.com).
We need to protect our ClientAPP with siteminder here but also which can be done easily, complexity here is, for downloading the files instead of using APIController i have used MVCController for its FILECONTENTRESULT behaviour, so basically i redirect my users(when they click on the file links provided on angular UI) to that controller using:

$window.location.href="DOWNLOADCONTROLLER/DownloadFile/IDOfTheDocument"

In turn this url returns the intended file by searching it on the basis of id provided in URL and returns filecontentresult which automatically downloads the file on browser.

We need another functionality where we can share this download file URL with other users, we need to implement security around this URL as well which is part of RESTAPI MVC app, we are marking our options on "how do we protect this URL" since it's an MVC controller we cannot go for token based security like we have done it for API controllers so and also we cannot share tioken with users so, is it possible make this URL siteminder protected so that when user hits this url from browser instead of app it gets the SSO login screen? if yes, how do we ensure that when my user is already logged in to client app,REST API doesn't ask for authentication when he tries to download the file from the client APP,.

Comment: This question is quite broad, and it's likely to generate negative attention or just be completely ignored in it's current state.  Instead of telling us what you need, and asking yes/no questions like "is it possible...", you should try to demonstrate what you have tried, and **specific** challenges you are having with your approach.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for a quick reply, point is this app is still in development phase for which we did a POC with angularJS and webapi, this is a future requirement we have to make it secured using Siteminder,

Comment: to be more specific.

how to check SMESESSION cookie in RESTAPI using C#?